# MVC3 Actionlink redirects to wrong controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a controller ProgramSummary that I want to redirect to a second controller TRPResource. In the first controller for the detail view I have an actionLink:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Resource(s)", "TRPDetails", "TRPResource", new { ttl = ViewBag.shrt_titles })
```

It redirects to Requested URL: `/ProgramSummary/TRPDetails` which is the correct view but the wrong controller. If I change the actionLink to read (as follows)

```
@Html.ActionLink("Resource(s)", "TRPDetails", "TRPResource")
```

The actionlink works as I intend and goes to the correct controller and view but the problem being that the value is not maintained in the ViewBag and is not passed. What is the concept that I am missing here and/or can a work around or different approach be suggested?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are using a wrong overload of the ActionLink helper. You should use the [correct overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972.aspx) (notice the `null` at the end):

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "Resource(s)",                        // linkText
    "TRPDetails",                         // actionName
    "TRPResource",                        // controllerName
    new { ttl = ViewBag.shrt_titles },    // routeValues
    null                                  // htmlAttributes
)
```

whereas your code is using the [following overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492124.aspx):

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "Resource(s)",                     // linkText
    "TRPDetails",                      // actionName
    "TRPResource",                     // routeValues
    new { ttl = ViewBag.shrt_titles }  // htmlAttributes
)
```

Notice the problem?

Answer (score 0):

ActionLink helper uses your routing configuration to build URLs from supplied route values. It is probable that you have some route which it hits before the one you want to get hit. Your routing seems pretty simple, so you just look at routes carefully. In more complex scenarious, you can use **routing debugger**

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx